# Copying a rendered PHP file that uses firewalled APIs from LAN to WWW

Tags: php, api, rendering, server-side-includes

Problem: I have three Bitcoin miners, all with APIs for mining stats and device info. All three ASICs are inside my private, firewalled LAN. I have a PHP script consolidating information from these devices and displaying the most important information, dashboard style, using PHP to read and display the data. Currently I am trying to find a solution that allows me to check on the same dashboard and locally available ASIC reporting from the globally addressed WWW, and have ran into issues getting a rendered version of my dashboard on the web for viewing since it is outside my LAN and thus cannot "see" the BTC miners when rendered server-side from the PHP outside my LAN. A Raspberry Pi 2 is currently internally rendering the displayed page of information. Just using scp to move the page outside the LAN renders the dashboard an empty template. I am trying to find a way to upload a rendered version of a single PHP file using server-side includes etc. I am hoping to achieve this programmatically if possible.

...And here is where it gets more confusing: attempting to solve (and not just describe) my issue:

Solutions:

1. html2canvas which claims to a essentially screenshot the display buffer of a local web browser for output as a JPEG or other image
2. A vague suggestion that I may want to display PHP's output buffer and copy the subsequently rendered HTML code from there
3. A very vague "big picture" solution that makes reference to handling web servers Promise's as if my code was rendering the PHP the same way it would if I was writing my own web-browser.

As you can see, these answers all seem awfully complex (as does the only solution I can think of: have the PHP run LAN-side on RPi "A", perform one of the above solutions on LAN-side RPI "B" (html2canvas worked for my needs-- until I sent it to the final www-accessible but firewalled-off server; maybe moving the 'render and display' steps away from the original server and onto a second LAN-side web server for then copying to a web-addressable server would solve the problems? I feel that the actual trouble is happening because a single server is both performing the programmatic creation of the final markup for rendering / viewing in a browser and actually trying to serve and display / render already computed HTML simultaneously maybe?) Finally, the server used to display the rendered markup could re-encode and upload the output from itself to an externally addressable web server, including data otherwise only available on my LAN and prior to any server trying to re-render the PHP on load.

Any assistance would be warmly welcomed. Thanks in advance for your advice on this problem; I apologize for any ambiguity regarding my issue and understand it is a rather confusing edge-case. If this isn't the best place to seek assistance or if you believe you can help me even just in describing the issue more clearly, please let me know (still fairly new here)!

Comment: It appears that I might be looking for something like ReactJS, although an entire framework for one task seems overkill. Please advise! Thanks!